# WEP Encryption for WiFI Hotspot in KitKat

Tags: wifi-hotspot, wep

Is it possible to enable WEP encryption for the hotspot function in Android 4.4? It only shows WPA and WPA2 for me and I would like to create a WEP hotspot.

Alternatively, are there any hotspot apps that support WEP? All the ones I found just refer to the inbuilt hotspot functionality.

Comment: Why would you need a weaker encryption (WEP) over strong one? And I'm sure there is no such app too...

Comment: I need it for a live demonstration on WEP security in university, I am aware of the risks

Comment: I don't know whether it is a software limitation or hardware limitation but there are no apps like this. Use a router with WEP for demo instead ;)

Comment: WEP is so weak that there's effectively no difference security-wise between using it or not. Providing the option meant users could mistakenly believe they had some level of protection in-place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since WEP encryption is very, very insecure it was replaced by WPA/2. 
Creating WEP encrypted WiFi networks today is very risky because it can be hacked within seconds.
So the answer is you can't create a WEP encrypted WiFi Hotspot with Android.

BTW:
An app can only use hotspot features the device is supporting. And because the newer Androids don't support WEP there is no way for the apps to create hotspots with WEP.

Comment: Are you sure? I did find an app named Barnacle which let me use WEP. However I wasn't able to run it, possibly due to it being written for Android 2.2 or similar. I would think a Hotspot app can implement any security it wants if it does so from scratch.

Comment: Yes I am sure. As you said this app is for Android 2.2 which was supporting the insecure WEP encryption.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Seems like I'm gonna have to use a dedicated access point.

Comment: Why do you need WEP?

Comment: See my comment on the question itself.

Comment: Okay. You could thy to use a Windows-Laptop and open a hotspot/ad-hoc network. Windows hasn't dropped WEP Hotspot support yet.

Comment: Problem is, I need at least one client and one attacker notebook and I have only two. I should be able to use a normal router. though, so it's fine. Thanks for your help :)